# ggplot `geom_segment()` fails to recognize `group_by()` specification

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df <- 
  tibble(Date = as.Date(0:364, origin = "2017-07-01"), Value = rnorm(365)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = str_sub(Date, 1, 4), 
         MoFloor = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>% 
  group_by(Year, MoFloor) %>% 
  mutate(MoAvgValue = mean(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(MinMoFloor = min(MoFloor),
         MaxMoFloor = max(MoFloor),
         YearAvgValue = mean(MoAvgValue))
#> # A tibble: 365 x 8
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>    Date         Value Year  MoFloor   
#>    <date>       <dbl> <chr> <date>    
#>  1 2017-07-01 -1.83   2017  2017-07-01
#>  2 2017-07-02 -2.13   2017  2017-07-01
#>  3 2017-07-03  1.49   2017  2017-07-01
#>  4 2017-07-04  0.0753 2017  2017-07-01
#>  5 2017-07-05 -0.437  2017  2017-07-01
#>  6 2017-07-06 -0.327  2017  2017-07-01
#>  7 2017-07-07 -1.28   2017  2017-07-01
#>  8 2017-07-08  0.280  2017  2017-07-01
#>  9 2017-07-09  1.24   2017  2017-07-01
#> 10 2017-07-10  0.0921 2017  2017-07-01
#> # ... with 355 more rows, and 4 more
#> #   variables: MoAvgValue <dbl>,
#> #   MinMoFloor <date>,
#> #   MaxMoFloor <date>,
#> #   YearAvgValue <dbl>
```

Let's first plot the data frame above.

```
ggplot(df, aes(MoFloor, MoAvgValue, group = Year)) + 
  facet_grid(~Year, scale = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot1]

In my call to the `facet_grid()` function I added the arguments `scale = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` to get rid of empty white space on the plots.

When I go ahead and add `geom_segment()`s based on `group_by()`d data, the `scale = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` arguments are negated. The empty white space reappears!

```
ggplot(df, aes(MoFloor, MoAvgValue, group = Year)) + 
  facet_grid(~Year, scale = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(data = df, 
               aes(x = min(MinMoFloor), 
                   y = YearAvgValue, 
                   xend = max(MaxMoFloor), 
                   yend = YearAvgValue))
```

[image: plot2]

My `df` data frame is grouped by `Year`. Why doesn't the `geom_segment()` function recognize this when I enter (for example) the `x = min(MinMoFloor)` argument? `geom_segment()` is pulling the `min(MinMoFloor)` from the global column, instead of the grouped column. How do I `geom_segment()` to evaluate the `MinMoFloor` column as grouped data?

Comment: `ggplot` doesn't generally recognize groups. You're better off calculating your endpoints beforehand instead of trying to do those calculations inside a geom

Comment: @camille thanks for that tip. Calculating endpoints is trivial for this simple example. But my actual problem has dozens of facets and I'd need some type of programmatic solution.

Comment: So you should do these same calculations outside of your plotting functions, and then use that data frame for endpoints

Comment: @camille isn't that what I did with my `MinMoFloor` and `MaxMoFloor` columns? Pardon me but I think I'm missing your point. If I had to do everything manually it would be burdensome for plots with many facets.

Comment: For the first set of calculations, yes. But you're then trying to get min & max within groups inside your `geom_segment`, but the grouping won't hold there. Do *those* calculations beforehand. Or do them inline as the `geom_segment(data = __)` argument. Just can't get it to work with grouping inside the `aes` as you have it

Comment: If this is your actual use case (different horizontal line across each facet), I'm not sure why `geom_segment` is even warranted. Is there any reason why something like `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = YearAvgValue))` won't work for you?

Comment: I would ideally like something that would work on horizontal lines, and also work on lines that are diagonal, but it looks like that solution is not coming. `geom_hline()` will have to be my temporary solution. Thank you.